# What do the three numbers used by Ramius when giving directions mean in The Hunt for Red October?

Tags: the-hunt-for-red-october

Around 28:20 in the movie, after Ramius' opening speech for Red October's mission and while the crew is singing the Soviet anthem, he gives the numbers 2/5/0 to his navigator to use as a direction.

I've seen this three-numbers system used in a lot of sci-fi and I always brushed it off as technobabble, but this is the first time I've seen it in a historical fiction that aims for technical realism, so I guess these numbers do mean something. And searching with something as vague as "three numbers", "navigation", "direction" and "submarine" isn't precise enough for Google.

Am I right in assuming this three-numbers system is (or was) used in the real world? If so, does it have a specific name and what do the numbers represent?

Comment: In most space-based sci-fi, bearings are usually spoken in the form "two-five-zero _mark_ zero-one-four" because you need (and only need) two angles to set a direction in 3-dimensional space (I think Battlestar Galactic used a word like _karam_ instead to make it more spacey, but the I idea is the same).

Comment: First five results when I typed "250 direction" into Google: https://uni.edu/storm/Wind%20Direction%20slide.pdf http://snowfence.umn.edu/Components/winddirectionanddegrees.htm http://tamivox.org/dave/compass/index.html https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Points_of_the_compass https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/26549/how-is-wind-direction-reported-blowing-from-or-blowing-to

Comment: Before people used GPS on their phones, they often used a compass: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compass

Comment: @Polygnome And there's no GPS on a sub.  And last week I encountered directions given as compass bearings, as well as a detailed set of GPS coordinates that would require some technology to use, they weren't meant for human consumption.

Comment: @LorenPechtel I'm well aware that there is no GPS on a sub. This was more a comment on the fact that in the past, people would know what headings are because they regularly encounter them in real life. With smartphones and map apps that use GPS, encountering headings in everyday live has declined.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I believe this is just a [bearing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bearing_%28navigation%29), a standard method of navigation that uses the 360 degrees of a circle, with 0 at true north, like so:

[image]

A bearing of "2-5-0" would be 250 degrees, which is roughly west-by-southwest. Saying the digits one-by-one ("two five zero" instead of "two-hundred-and-fifty") reduces the risk of miscommunications that could lead you off-course ("I thought you said two-hundred-and-fif*teen*!").

Comment: Like "[m as in Mancy"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dNYMQpcqscA)?

Comment: Yep, that's exactly the point of phonetic alphabets as well - to reduce the chance of critical information being misheard.

Comment: When commanding a ship change direction (in this case, a boat) are bearings given as _absolute_ (e.g., with 0° being "north" whatever that is) or _relative_ to the direction the ship is currently headed?

Comment: Steer 250 would be with 0 degrees beeing north. Relative bearings would be given as red or green (red 90 would be straight off to the left, known as port).  Also note that where "North" is depends on a number of factors (a magnetic compass will not necessarily point at the geographic north pole, search for "magnetic declination"). In this case though it does not matter as they use the same gyro compass to get bearings. (More fun reading "gyrocompass")

Comment: @davidbak: Absolute, although there's some ambiguity as to whether they're true or magnetic.

Comment: @davidbak How would relative work? The moment you try to steer to 250 *relative*, your  reference frame changes. You'd try to to catch your own tail, so to speak.

Comment: @davidbak Here's a reference card for US Navy helm commands (I assume the HFRO Russian Navy would be similar): http://www.boatswainsmate.net/BM/helmcmds.pdf.

Comment: I would assume that if a relative bearing were used, it would be something like "port 1-1-0" (with a direction and a value between 0 and 180, or more realistically something between 0 and 90, since you aren't going to pivot the boat to reverse your direction immediately).

Comment: I also assume its the job of the helmsman to translate a newly requested absolute heading into a series of course changes to achieve the new heading.